# How to select some items in the UICollectionView after it first load?

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I tried to write

`[self collectionView:myCollectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath]`

and UICollectionViewCell's selected=YES in viewDidLoad, and it did implemented the method `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, but the cell not selected.

I wrote the selected state in UICollectionViewCell subclass's `(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected`. After the view was load, the manual selection function works. But I could't let it auto selected some items after the view's first load.

And I tried to write codes in:

`- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

and

`- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, all not OK.

I found it first run `viewDidLoad` and `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, then `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, it seems like that I could't get the cell in the `indexPath` (that I know) before `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, because before that the cell is not exist. So how to select some items in the `UICollectionView` after it first load?

Sorry for my poor english. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure, if got your question correct, but here's a possible solution:

In e.g. `viewWillAppear:` do

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
NSIndexPath *selection = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:THE_ITEM_TO_SELECT 
                                             inSection:THE_SECTION];
[self.collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:selection 
                                  animated:YES 
                            scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Bear in mind, that calling 'selectItemAtIndexPath' programmatically does NOT call the related delegate methods; you'll have to call them in code if you need them.

Comment: Thank you! I have worked it out! I always used the wrong code:[self collectionView:_tagsCollectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath] and tried to put it everywhere, not the selectItemAtIndexPath, so always not work.

Comment: When my view is loaded this method works good for me. But in my view I have thumbs that are selected automatically

Comment: And what is exactly your problem? The original question was about the first load of the view.

Comment: This worked well for me as long as I did it "late enough". For example, it works in viewDidLoad, but does not work in collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:, viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear.

Comment: Follow On: Even in viewDidLoad, I would only see the selection work for 1 cell. By moving the selection to viewDidLayoutSubviews, I was able to select multiple cells.

Answer (score 9):

In my case `selectItemAtIndexPath` had no effect after `reloadData`, so I had to call it in the completion block of `performBatchUpdates`:

```
collectionView.dataSource = ...
collectionView.delegate = ...

let indexPath = ...

collectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil) { _ in
  collectionView.selectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .None)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was in the same situation of making selectItem action after reloadData. Your answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3

Implement this override function where is  your collectionview is created.
Assuming that we have 1 section 1 row like Instagram stories.

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // Auto Select First Item
        self.myCollectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil) { _ in
            self.myCollectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: [.centeredHorizontally])
            self.collectionView(self.myCollectionView, didSelectItemAt : IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0))
        }
    }
```